# Show as simply as possible that $\mathbb Q$ has an extension with Galois group $S_n$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

It is well known that if we take a random polynomial (monic with
integer coefficients, say), then it will "almost always" be irreducible
and have Galois group $S_n$ (see, for example,
this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58397/the-galois-group-of-a-random-polynomial) ). The tools in the proof are quite advanced
however.

Consider the much weaker statement : (*) For every $n\geq 2$, there is an
extension of $\mathbb Q$ with Galois group $S_n$.

(this statement is exactly what is needed to finish another recent
MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470010/commutant-of-generic-matrix-with-polynomial-coefficients/1470133#1470133) )

So here goes my challenge : find a proof of (*) that's as elementary and
self-contained as possible (but not simpler as Einstein would say).

Comment: It's not so hard for $n$ prime. All you need is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ with exactly two nonreal roots.

Comment: I found another exposition, pp 104-105 of Richard Koch's notes on Galois Theory, available at http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/Galois.pdf – it's still longer than anything I'd want to type out here, but skimming it (I haven't read it closely) it looks promising.

Comment: Makoto Kato wrote up an exposition at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165675/constructing-a-galois-extension-field-with-galois-group-s-n – the last part of it looks very much like the last part of Koch's write-up.

Comment: See also http://www.nptel.ac.in/courses/111101001/downloads/Lecture26.pdf also http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~vonk/2012JNT1.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for all the links, I'll look them up when I have the time

Answer (score 1):

Theorem 37 of Hadlock, Field Theory and Its Classical Problems, #19 in the MAA Carus Mathematical Monographs series, is

For every positive integer $n$, there exists a polynomial over $\bf Q$ whose Galois group is $S_n$.

The proof is only half a page long, BUT it comes as the culmination of a long chapter, which suggests to me that any self-contained proof will be too long for anyone to want to write it out here. But maybe you could have a look at it, to see whether you'd be able to post a summary (or to get a better idea of just how hard the question is).